# OG group - Edit permissions of groups for specific role

Tags: organic-groups, users

I don't have too much experience with OG so I would be glad if someone could help me. Basically scenario is:

I use organic groups for microsite creation, so I have a content type which is called "Microsite" and it is set as a og group. I have some other content types which can belong to the group.

I want to create a role "Microsite admin" who will be able only edit existing groups (in this case microsites) and only specific fields which are on the microsite content type (This part I think I can solve with field [permission module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions))

Og allows only group manage edit a group or someone who belongs to the group and have permissions to edit it.

In my case I want to have a one global role who will be able edit all groups and specific fields on it. (So basically someone who doesn't belong to any group and have admin permission to edit them).